# State inside of component doesn't update on setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state, react-props

I am trying to set the state of a self updating Date-obj in my App.js file.
The state is then passed down into the ***DateTime*** component and works initially fine. But when the state of ***date*** updates itself with a setInterval() timer, it doesn't change the state (or time) inside of the component I "drilled" the prop ***date*** down to. Shouldn't the ***DateTime*** component update itself every second as well? How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import DateTime from './components/DateTime';


const App = () => {

  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  const hours = date.getHours();

  function refreshClock() {
    setDate(new Date());
  }


useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
}, []);


  return (

      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen w-screen">
        <DateTime date={date} />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**DateTime.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'



const DateTime = ({date}) => {

    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? `0${date.getMinutes()}` : date.getMinutes();
    const currentTime = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
  
    const weekdays = ['Sonntag','Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch','Donnerstag','Freitag','Samstag' ];
    const weekday = weekdays[date.getDay()];
    const currentDate = `${day}.${month}.${year}`;

    return (
  
        <div className="z-10">
        <p className="dark:text-black text-white text-center text-10xl leading-11">{currentTime}</p>
        <p className="dark:text-black text-white text-center text-4xl">{weekday}, der {currentDate}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component updates. You can check it if you add seconds to currentTime.

```
  const seconds = date.getSeconds();
  const currentTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't update automatically. When I refresh the page, the time is updated. But not through the setInterval-timer from the useEffect in App.js.